# Replace every second and third item in list with 0

Tags: python

I have a randomly generated list of items, and I want to replace every second and third item in that list with the number 0. For the replacement of every second item I have used the code below.

```
import random

x = [random.randint(0,11) for x in range(1000)]
y = [random.randint(0,11) for x in range(1000)]
a = (x + y)
a[::2] = [0]*(2000//2)
print(a)
```

It works fine, but I can't use the same method with replacing every third item since it gives me an error

> attempt to assign sequence of size 666 to extended slice of size 667

I thought of using list comprehension, but I'm unsure of how to execute it, and I could not find a definite answer in my research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace `2000//2` with `len(a[::2])` like this

```
import random

x = [random.randint(0,11) for x in range(1000)]
y = [random.randint(0,11) for x in range(1000)]

a = (x + y)
a[::2] = [0]*len(a[::2])
print(a)

b = (x + y)
b[::3] = [0]*len(b[::3])
print(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the case of every second element, the size of `[0]*(2000//2)` is equal to the size of `a[::2]`, which is 1000. That is why you are not getting an error. But in the case of `a[::3]`, there are 667 elements and `[0]*(2000//3)` returns a list of size 666, which is not possible to assign. You can use `math.ceil` to solve this issue. As:

```
import random
from math import ceil

x = [random.randint(0, 11) for x in range(1000)]
y = [random.randint(0, 11) for x in range(1000)]
a = (x + y)
index = 2
a[::index] = [0] * ceil(2000/index)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite as neat as subscripting the list outright, but this can be done with the `%` operator and indices:

```
import random

x = [random.randint(0,11) for x in range(1000)]
y = [random.randint(0,11) for x in range(1000)]
a = (x + y)

for i, v in enumerate(a):
    if (i+1) % 2 == 0 or (i+1) % 3 == 0:
        a[i] = 0

# if you prefer a comprehension:
a = [0 if (i+1) % 3 == 0 or (i+1) % 2 == 0 else v for i, v in enumerate(a)] 

print(a)
```

```
[3, 6, 0, 5, 1, 0, 8, 5, 0, 1, 5, 0, 2, 3, 0, 7, 9, 0, ... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, where every other or every 3rd become zero.

```
[0 if (i+1)%2==0 or (i+1)%3==0 else x for i, x in enumerate(a)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have explained how replacement is done, but the same result could be achieved by *not* generating these random throwaway numbers in the first place.

```py
from random import randint
N = 2_000

[randint(0, 11) if (x % 2) * (x % 3) != 0 else 0
    for x in range(1, N + 1)]
```

Answer (score -2):

To get this done efficiently I would recommend using the numpy module here is the code

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0,12,(2000,))
a[::2] = 0
a[::3] = 0
a = a.tolist()
print(a)
```

np.random.randint takes in 3 arguments. the first is the lower bound inclusive, the second is the upper bound exclusive and the third is a tuple of the array dimensions. In this case a 1-d array of 2000. using numpy you can just use slicing to set the parts you want to zero and then use tolist() to convert back to a list if you need to or keep it as a numpy array.

Comment: Numpy seems overkill for this, it's a huge library which take a lot of resources to be downloaded and loaded